# Building and Installing .Net Framework on Linux

Tags: .net, linux, roslyn

I have cloned the corefw (open source .Net framework code) and the roslyn complier code. Please let me know if there is any steps or guide to install .NetFramework and write application on that.

Repo Links:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn, 
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx

Comment: There is a Getting Started page (dotnet.github.io/core/getting-started) that explains how to install dnvm, dnx and dnu and how to build a sample console application.